# Python 2 - Cannot figure out why I am getting invalid literal for int() error message

Tags: python

Complete beginner question here, but after scouring this site and the internet for several hours, I still can't come up with a reason as to why I am getting this error.

I am trying to use `.split()` to get all the integers out of a `.txt` file with a simple python program.  I want to learn how to do this so I can start to tackle more complex tasks. This is what I have so far.

```
import sys
test = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

for num in test:
    answer = [int(x) for x in num.split()]
    print answer
```

Every time I try to enter this at the command prompt `python test.py test.txt` I get invalid literal for `int()` error message.  My `test.txt` file is a single line file formatted like so:

`1 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100`

Each number is separated by a single space.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Edit: I just realized I should say that I am using notepad++ to write these python programs, and the windows 8 powershell to run and test them.

Edit: I created a brand new .txt file called test1.txt and the code works.  I am saving my original test.txt file because the problem is interesting and a solution technically wasn't found.  If it means anything, I created test.txt using an echo command in powershell so, echo "1 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100">test.txt and the new test1.txt file inside notepad++

Comment: you may want to try `for num in test.read()`

Comment: the error message should say what the literal is, as in `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: <ACTUAL VALUE>`.  what is it?

Comment: I would try iterating over `num.split()` to see *which* value `int` is complaining about. It should be able to ignore trailing newlines (unix or dos), but I wonder if your file *begins* with a BOM, in which case it's the first call to `int` that may have the problem.

Comment: It was a problem with the text.txt file. This is solved I think.  Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have extra characters at end of file. You could wrap the `int()` in a `try/except` block and report what it sees. Something like this:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fin:
    for line in fin:
       try:
           print [int(x) for x in line.split()]
       except ValueError:
           print("unexpected input %r" % line)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that.  I found something wrong with the txt file itself.  I made a brand new txt file called test1.txt and my code works, which is a positive note.  I have no clue why it did this, I will post a snippet of the error:  "unexpected input \xff\xfe1x00 x001\x000"  I am saving my test.txt file because this is interesting and I'd like to understand why this specific txt file does not work with my code.  If it means anything, I created test.txt in powershell using echo "1 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100">test.txt

Comment: Sounds like a windows byte order mark (BOM) -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Is this a common occurrence with txt files? Can one program a fix in their python script to make sure the txt file is compatibility with the users code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're facing problem with new line chars in the last column of each line. Not sure but removing leading and trailing characters for each line might solve:

```
for num in test:
    num = num.strip()
    answer = [int(x) for x in num.split()]   
    print answer
```

Comment: `int` already knows how to strip newlines from the end of its input.

Comment: For that matter so does `split()`.

Comment: @chepner Oh, it's true. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If each number is separated by a single space then add that space to your split command:

```
[int(x) for x in line.split(' ')]
```

Comment: `split()` with no argument splits on arbitrary whitespace (including a single space).

Comment: it ought to work the was he has it then... there must be an inconsistency in the file.